# How to reverse a linked list using recursion?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to reverse a linked list using recursion. I had previously written code to do this using a simple `while` loop and it worked perfectly. I can't figure out why my recursion code isn't working.

```
#include<iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};

class LinkedLists
{
    private: 
    node* head;
    node* temp;
    
    public:
    LinkedLists() // default constructor
    {
        head = NULL;
        temp = NULL;
    }

    void add_data(int d)
    {   
        node* new_node = new node; // create a pointer to the new node
        new_node->next = NULL;
        new_node->data = d;
        if (head == NULL)
        {   head = new_node;
            temp = head;
        }
        else
        {   
            temp = head;
            while(temp->next != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = new_node; // final node now points to the new_node
        }

    }

    void print_list()
    {
        temp = head;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            std::cout<<temp->data<<" ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    void reverse()
    {
        // reverse a linked list
        node* prev_node;
        node* next_node;
        node* temp_ptr;

        prev_node = NULL;
        temp_ptr = head;
        next_node = temp_ptr->next;

        while(next_node != NULL)
        {
            temp_ptr->next = prev_node;
            prev_node = temp_ptr;
            temp_ptr = next_node;
            next_node = temp_ptr->next;
        }

        temp_ptr->next = prev_node;

        head = temp_ptr;

    }

    void repeat(node* prev_node, node* temp_ptr,node* next_node)
    {
        temp_ptr->next = prev_node;
        prev_node = temp_ptr;
        temp_ptr = next_node;

        if (next_node != NULL)
        {
            next_node = temp_ptr->next;
            repeat(prev_node,temp_ptr,next_node);
        }
        head = temp_ptr;
    }

    void recursive_reverse()
    {
        node* prev_node;
        node* next_node;
        node* temp_ptr;

        prev_node = NULL;
        temp_ptr = head;
        next_node = temp_ptr->next;

        repeat(prev_node,temp_ptr,next_node);

    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedLists l; // create a linked list object
    l.add_data(110);
    l.add_data(140);
    l.add_data(101);
    l.add_data(140);
    l.add_data(101);
    l.add_data(140);
    l.add_data(101);
    l.add_data(120);

    cout<<endl;
    l.print_list();


    l.reverse();

    cout<<endl;
    l.print_list();


    l.recursive_reverse();
    cout<<endl;
    l.print_list();

}
```

Ouput:

```
110 140 101 140 101 140 101 120
120 101 140 101 140 101 140 110
101 120
```

Expected output:

```
110 140 101 140 101 140 101 120
120 101 140 101 140 101 140 110
110 140 101 140 101 140 101 120
```

Comment: Unrelated: You use `new` but not `delete`. Your program leaks. Fixing that is more important than reversing it I'd say.

Comment: Where should I use `delete`? Wouldn't that delete the node? Or should I not use `new` in the first place?

Comment: If you create a `LinkedLists` and fill it with data and the `LinkedLists` goes out of scope - it's supposed to clear all the memory it's allocated. You just leave it allocated. If you do this in a loop you'll run out of memory eventually. You can sometimes use smart pointers but for this type of thing, raw pointers is probably what you want - but it makes memory management really important. A first step could be a destructor, like: `~LinkedList() { for(node* temp; head; head = temp) { temp = head->next; delete head; } }` or similar.

Comment: So, as pptaszni said I need to implement a destructor for the `LinkedLists` class, right?

Comment: About the `delete` question: just implement the destructor `LinkedLists::~LinkedLists()` which will delete all previously allocated data. You can also do it recursively, however usually it is better to do this kind of things iteratively for large objects.

Comment: Okay got it! I will do that

Comment: @Yatin Yes, you need a destructor (like the one I showed above) but you also need to think about [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: @Yatin You selected as the best answer the answer that suggests you a recursive function with undefined behavior when the function is called for an empty list.:) So in fact you selected a bad answer.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters it is unclear why the class of the linked list has a plural name.

```
class LinkedLists
               ^^^
```

It will be more natural to name it like `LinkedList` without ending `'s'`.

The data member `temp` is redundant and should be removed. Instead you can substitute this data member for local variables in member functions.

The structure `node` should be a private member of the class `LinkedList`.

I have not looked through all your function implementations but the function `recursive_reverse` can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class LinkedList
{
private: 
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        node* next;
    } *head = nullptr;


public:
    LinkedList() = default;

    // These two special member functions you can implement yourself
    LinkedList( const LinkedList &) = delete;
    LinkedList & operator =( const LinkedList & ) = delete;

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        clear();
    }
    
    void clear()
    {
        while ( head )
        {
            delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
        }
    }
    
    void add_data( int d )
    {   
        node **current = &head;
        
        while ( *current ) current = &( *current )->next;
        
        *current = new node { d, nullptr };
    }       

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const LinkedList &list )
    {
        for ( const node *current = list.head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
        {
            os << current->data << " -> ";
        }
        
        return os << "null";
    }

    void recursive_reverse()
    {
        if ( head != nullptr && head->next != nullptr )
        {
            node *current = head;
            head = head->next;
            
            recursive_reverse();
            
            current->next->next = current;
            current->next = nullptr;
        }
    }
};

int main() 
{
    LinkedList list; // create a linked list object
    const int N = 10;
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        list.add_data( i );
    }       

   
    std::cout << list << '\n';


    list.recursive_reverse();

    std::cout << list << '\n';

    list.recursive_reverse();

    std::cout << list << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> null
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```

If to use an auxiliary function for the member function `recursive_reverse` then the function should be a private static member function. The user of the list shall not call it directly.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class LinkedList
{
private: 
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        node* next;
    } *head = nullptr;

    static void repeat( node *previous, node * &head )
    {
        if ( head )
        {
            node *current = head;
            
            if ( head->next ) 
            {
                head = head->next;
                repeat( current, head );
            }
            
            current->next = previous;
        }
    }
    
public:
    LinkedList() = default;
    ~LinkedList()
    {
        clear();
    }
    
    void clear()
    {
        while ( head )
        {
            delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
        }
    }
    
    void add_data( int d )
    {   
        node **current = &head;
        
        while ( *current ) current = &( *current )->next;
        
        *current = new node { d, nullptr };
    }       

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const LinkedList &list )
    {
        for ( const node *current = list.head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
        {
            os << current->data << " -> ";
        }
        
        return os << "null";
    }
    
    void recursive_reverse()
    {
        repeat( nullptr, head );
    }
};

int main() 
{
    LinkedList list; // create a linked list object
    const int N = 10;
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        list.add_data( i );
    }       

   
    std::cout << list << '\n';


    list.recursive_reverse();

    std::cout << list << '\n';

    list.recursive_reverse();

    std::cout << list << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> null
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```

Comment: That `recursive_reverse` is pretty neat!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is superfluous, you don't need that many local variables and function arguments to implement recursion. Also in this part:

```
        if (next_node != NULL)
        {
            next_node = temp_ptr->next;
            repeat(prev_node,temp_ptr,next_node);
        }
        head = temp_ptr;
```

you seem to assign `nullptr` to your `head` when `next_node == nullptr`.

Corrected version:

```
    void repeat(node* previous, node* current)
    {
      node* next_node = current->next;
      current->next = previous;
      if (next_node == nullptr)
      {
        head = current;
        return;
      }
      repeat(current, next_node);
    }

    void recursive_reverse()
    {
        repeat(nullptr, head);
    }
```

Apart from that you have a memory leaks, because you never `delete` the memory that you allocated. Implement the destructor and mark your copy constructors/assignments as `deleted` explicitly (or you can also implement them, if you have time):

```
LinkedLists(const LinkedLists& other) = delete;
```

to avoid further bugs and to comply with [the rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (or five, or zero).